# Testing Jersey resourse with parameters

Tags: java, rest, jersey, integration-testing

I'm using Jersey resourse in my project, like:

```
@Path("/api")
  public class MyResource {

    @Path("/create")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response handle(final String xml, @Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
.....
}
```

and I'm trying to test it:

```
public class MobipayResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    private MockHttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        servletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        servletRequest.setMethod("POST");
    }

    public MobipayResourceTest() throws TestContainerException {
        super("ua.privatbank.mobipay.api.resource");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRes(){
        WebResource webResource = resource();
        webResource.path("/api/create").post(???); // I need to pass 2 parameters in the request - xml (in the body of post) and HttpServletRequest


    }
```

How can I pass 2 my parameters (String xml and HttpServletRequest) to the resourse in test?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the HttpServletRequest, I believe.
As to the xml parameter, I think you should have a parameter 
of some other class there, not just of type String. For example 
Item, Customer, Order, i.e. any business object (bean, POJO). 

The way you've done  it now, you'd better declare 
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) because you declare that 
you expect just a String in your method. Normally when
you expect XML, this XML value is unmarshalled into 
an object of some type (usually a bean, POJO, etc). You 
get this on the fly and you can just work with the object.

Here is some sample code of a sample Java client.

```
    package com.company.api.test;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
    import com.company.common.DateUtil;
    import com.company.api.input.ItemOperation;
    import com.company.api.input.ItemOperationData;
    import com.company.api.result.ItemResult;

    public class JavaClientREST {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

            ItemOperation op1 = new ItemOperation();
            op1.setItemID("447");
            Date d1 = DateUtil.getDate(2013, Calendar.DECEMBER, 20);
            System.out.println("DT1 = " + sdf.format(d1));
            op1.setDate(d1);
            op1.setOperation("pause");

            String res = service.path("Item")
                                .entity(op1, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .post(String.class);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ItemResult result = gson.fromJson(res, ItemResult.class);

            System.out.println("ID = [" + result.getId() + "]");
            System.out.println("Error = [" + result.getError() + "]");
            System.out.println("DONE!");
        }

        private static URI getBaseURI() {
            return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/api/service").build();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are right, I have POJO for mapping XML to it, but I still don't understand how should I pass POJO to the test method?
I need pass HttpServletRequest, cause I want to test some parameters from it in my business logic

Comment: @maxi 1) You can write a Java client and post the POJO, there're many examples on the web. 2) But you don't even need Java client actually, you just need a form which posts (method) some XML value to the URL (action) of your RESTful WS method.

Comment: @maxi Let me try to put together some example for you.

Comment: @maxi OK, I posted some sample code. This WS consumes XML but produces JSON. You can adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I  success passed my XML to resourse! But what about HttpServletRequest? I really need to pass it too.

Comment: @maxi I don't think so. I think it is something the web container initializes on its own. Put a debug statement and see what value it has when you POST some data to your REST WS method.